# My subprocess acts like a drive is mapped, but it's not. Fix?

Tags: python, windows, networking, subprocess

I'm making a script in Python 3.7 using the Spyder interpreter that uses the subprocess module to map a remote network drive to computers and then check if a file exists in that drive. For example, I'm mapping the drive on my computer as "S:\" but it's mapped to "C:\" on theirs. It's checking if the file "nircmd.exe" exists on their C:\. When I run my code all I get is:

```
[-] Could not connect to 10.98.80.142
[-] Could not connect to 10.98.80.147
```

When I print out: `b''`
When I print err: `'System error 85 has occurred.\r\n\r\nThe local device name is already in use.\r\n\r\n'`
Now I understand this is supposed to mean I already have the drive mapped, but I don't.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from os import path

def detectNircmd(computers):
    NIRCMD = "Windows\\System32\\nircmd.exe"
    valids = []
    invalids = []
    for computer in computers:
        try:
            p = Popen(['net', 'use', 'S:', '\\\%s\\c$' % computer],stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
            out, err = p.communicate()
            if 'success' in out:
                if path.isfile("S:\\%s" % NIRCMD):
                    valids.append(computer)
                    p = Popen(['net', 'use', 'S:', '/delete'],stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
                else:
                    invalids.append(computer)
                    p = Popen(['net', 'use', 'S:', '/delete'],stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
            else:
                invalids.append(computer)
                p = Popen(['net', 'use', 'S:', '/delete'],stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)

        except:
            print("[-] Could not connect to %s" % computer)
    print(valids, invalids)

tests = ['10.98.80.142', '10.98.80.147']
detectNircmd(tests)
```

Comment: You can list the drives defined in your current context via `import ctypes, string;` `d = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32').GetLogicalDrives();` `print([c for i,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase) if (d >> i) & 1])`. To show details for just mapped drives, run `import subrprocess;` `print(subprocess.run('net use', capture_output=True, encoding='oem').stdout)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out that there was something going wrong with using the try/except statements so I rewrote the algorithm without them and now it works.